# SSH “login” persists even after reboot

Tags: ssh

**E: Fixed. My mistake. I must have ticked the “automatically unlock this key on log in” box in the Gnome Keyring passphrase prompt, thinking that it means I would be *prompted* automatically at log in rather than not being prompted at all. Oh well.**

(Sorry, I have no idea how to search for this because a lot of people want their SSH passphrases to be remembered. They are blocking all the search results.)

I recently discovered that I no longer have to type in my SSH passphrase even after a reboot. I just get authenticated automatically for some reason. I don’t want that and I am starting to become a bit paranoid about it.

Any ideas what I can do to change this?

Thanks

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/419546/ssh-never-ask-for-a-password)

Comment: @Ravan: Found the “issue” (see edit). Thanks for the comment!

Comment: refer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/how-to-force-ssh-client-to-use-only-password-auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Dummy answer so I can (hopefully) mark the question as solved. I ticked a box in Gnome Keyring to automatically unlock the key on log in.)