# CLI needs sudo to be able to SSH

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-agent

I have a strange error. I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and copied over my SSH keys from the old installation (Ubuntu 20.04). Now suddenly I need `sudo` to be able to SSH to any machine - as long as it's not in the `.ssh/config`.

So something like `ssh@192.168.2.3` needs sudo, which shouldn't be the case - whilst `ssh randomserver` (in config) doesn't need sudo.

What can be worth noting is that I had the keys on Ubuntu 20.04 under `/root/.ssh`, while now I have moved everything to `/home/user/.ssh`. I have `chown'ed everything, so permissions should be fine.

I didn't find any info online, so I'm asking here. Do you know what's going on? It's pretty annoying having to type two passwords just to be able to SSH to anything...

**Here's a good example:**

```
daniel@xps9310:~$ ssh daniel@10.50.50.119
The authenticity of host '10.50.50.119 (10.50.50.119)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:YoCAfKKwVzweLXJea3YXz2q7D/6g8VadfbUXgK/wIsg.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.50.50.119' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
daniel@10.50.50.119: Permission denied (publickey,password).

daniel@xps9310:~$ sudo ssh daniel@10.50.50.119
The authenticity of host '10.50.50.119 (10.50.50.119)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:YoCAfKKwVzweLXJea3YXz2q7D/6g8VadfbUXgK/wIsg.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.50.50.119' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
daniel@10.50.50.119's password: 

Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-25-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

This system has been minimized by removing packages and content that are
not required on a system that users do not log into.

To restore this content, you can run the 'unminimize' command.
Last login: Fri May  6 12:21:00 2022
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

daniel@nextcloud:~$
```

**And my permissions on the .ssh folder:**

```
total 57
drwx------  3 daniel daniel     9 maj  6 12:46 .
drwxr-x--- 18 daniel daniel    25 maj  6 00:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 daniel daniel   406 aug  7  2018 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 daniel daniel 12898 apr  1 20:02 config
-rw-------  1 daniel daniel   399 mar  4 20:35 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r--  1 daniel daniel    95 mar  4 20:35 id_ed25519.pub
drwxr-x--- 64 daniel daniel    70 dec 27 10:33 keys
-rw-------  1 daniel daniel   648 maj  6 14:21 known_hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 daniel daniel   142 maj  6 00:31 known_hosts.old
```

**Running in debug mode**

```
daniel@xps9310:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvv daniel@10.50.50.119
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/daniel/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/daniel/.ssh/config line 457: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.50.50.119 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.50.50.119 [10.50.50.119] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.50.50.119:22 as 'daniel'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:YoCAfKKwVzweLXJea3YXz2q7D/6g8VadfbUXgK/wIsg
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying user hostfile "/home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts does not exist
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying user hostfile "/home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts2"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying system hostfile "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts does not exist
debug3: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: trying system hostfile "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2"
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
The authenticity of host '10.50.50.119 (10.50.50.119)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:YoCAfKKwVzweLXJea3YXz2q7D/6g8VadfbUXgK/wIsg.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.50.50.119' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:ESZ4F/mWckhBaqebvK7jh+oZ0SwDQP8sMUdvHzk7xIA agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:ESZ4F/mWckhBaqebvK7jh+oZ0SwDQP8sMUdvHzk7xIA agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
daniel@10.50.50.119: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

**SSH-version**

```
daniel@xps9310:~/.ssh$ dpkg -l | grep ssh
ii  libssh-4:amd64                             0.9.6-2build1                           amd64        tiny C SSH library (OpenSSL flavor)
ii  libssh-gcrypt-4:amd64                      0.9.6-2build1                           amd64        tiny C SSH library (gcrypt flavor)
ii  openssh-client                             1:8.9p1-3                               amd64        secure shell (SSH) client, for secure access to remote machines
```

**EDIT 1:**
Just found this, it's very similar to my issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/98289/ssh-doesnt-ask-for-password-gives-permission-denied-immediately

Comment: "permissions should be fine": please check them against this list: https://www.frankindev.com/2020/11/26/permissions-for-.ssh-folder-and-key-files/

Comment: Presumably, you have a `User` entry in the config, right? Can you show us an example (change the IP and username, if needed). Please [edit] your question and add that along with the _exact_ error message you receive and also the output of `ls -l ~/.ssh/`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I ran the permissions from the link, and also added an example in the main post.

Comment: Did you try with verbose mode? `ssh -v`. Multiple `-v` options increase the verbosity (`-vvv`). Manually choose which key to use with `-i`.

Comment: Please see updated post.

Comment: It looks like your client offers a key from your user-session's ssh-agent; I'm guessing when you use sudo it doesn't? (Recent versions of sudo default to set-home, so it likely looks for identity files in /root/.ssh in that case). Perhaps that's one difference worth exploring.

Comment: @steeldriver Hmm, not a bad guess at all!

I Googled a bit but didn't find a good answer... Do you mean I should change something in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`?

Comment: I read the SSH changelog, but maybe I missed something? https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html

Comment: If you do `sudo ssh ...` the ssh config of root (from `/root/.ssh`) is used. Seems root has the ssh-keys needed.

Comment: @Marco Yeah, that part is pretty clear. But it's strange since `/root/.ssh` is empty!

Comment: Shouldn't `/root/.ssh` at least contain a `known_hosts` file, since you accepted the host key from `sudo ssh ...` . Unless your *global* client config file `/etc/ssh_config` sets an alternate `UserKnownHostsFile`?

Comment: @steeldriver I actually removed `known_hosts` to make sure everything was clean.

Comment: @steeldriver The key thing here I think is that I copied everything from the old system which was in `/root/.ssh`, and maybe somehow, even if permissions were changed, it still hangs on in some strange way - even on a fresh system...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

This was the solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/419562/678954

Turned out to be that I had several Identityfiles. Removed the one in .ssh/config and voila!